# Each user can only use 1 GB of space in this one folder, and unlimited elsewhere

Tags: linux, backup, debian-squeeze, netatalk

I have a small problem. I have a folder called backups, and I have users who backup to this folder via a netatalk volume. I want each user to have a quota in this folder, say 1GB, but this quota only applies to files in this directory. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quotas apply to an entire volume. Simply mount a separate volume on that path, and set quotas appropriately.

Comment: I'm sorry, but how can you mount a folder as a volume. I do not understand linux fully, so this is a real learning experience for me

Comment: You don't. You mount a separate volume. As in, create a new volume and mount that.